# Iniciar sesión con un único usuario

Tags: php

Buen día tengo mi siguiente código:

```
<?php
include('conect.php');
$usurio= addslashes($_POST['uLogin']);
$password=addslashes($_POST['uPassword']);
$registro = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM iniciar where user ='$usurio'");
$comprobar = $registro ->num_rows;
if ($comprobar < 1) {

echo '0';
}else{

$incorrecto = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM iniciar where user ='$usurio' and password='$password'");

$correcto = $incorrecto->num_rows;

if ($correcto<1) {
        echo "2";

}else{

    $datos = $incorrecto -> fetch_assoc();

    $_SESSION['Usuario'] =$datos['user'];
    echo '1';       


}}
```

En mi base de datos tengo 4 usuarios con sus respectivas contraseñas. Pero lo que quiero hacer es que únicamente el usuario PabloNav pueda ingresar. 
Habrá alguna manera de que esto sea posible con SESSION, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes poner una condicion if que si $usurio es igual a "PabloNav" ejecute la consulta a la base de datos, si no no, algo asi:

```
include('conect.php');
$usurio= addslashes($_POST['uLogin']);
$password=addslashes($_POST['uPassword']);
if($usurio === "PabloNav") {
   $query= $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM iniciar where user ='$usurio' and 
password='$password'");
   $rows= $query->num_rows;
   if($rows > 0) {
      $datos = $query-> fetch_assoc();

      $_SESSION['Usuario'] =$datos['user'];
      echo '1';
   }else{
      echo '0';
   }
}else{
    echo '0';
}
```